# How can I use send receive for multiple values in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing, distributed-system, erlang-otp, erlang-ports

I have the following loops:

```
for( i = 1 ; i < V ; i++ )
{
    i sends "hi" to arr[i]
}

for( i = 1 ; i <arr.size ; i++ )
{
    if arr[i] receives "hi"
    {
        print "bye"
    }
}
```

How can i implement these codes in erlang?

I understood the simple ping and pong, but I want to create this code in parallel, so as to balance out the load. I am somewhat confused on the loop implementation part.

Comment: You have to use recursive or high-order functions. I could write the code for you but that will probably do you no good. I recommend you to check here first: https://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion

Comment: Thanks for your comment. do I need to create nodes or the simple send receive code will work? Loop are quite easy via recursion, yes. But won't it create kind of sequential behaviour?

Comment: Shall I use spawn?

Comment: Yeah, depending on what concurrency you want to achieve, you'll likely need to spawn processes within the recursive or high-order functions and those processes will need a receive statement.

Creating nodes is probably a bit too much, but then again… I don't know the specific requirements of your exercise.

Comment: Spawn should work then, I want to have a code faster than sequential, yes, nodes might be a bit too much. Again, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

worker() ->
    receive
        {hi, From} ->
            From ! {bye, self()},
            worker();
        stop ->
            io:format("Worker ~w terminated.~n", [self()]);
        _Other ->
            io:format("Bad message received by worker: ~w~n", [self()]),
            worker()
    end.


create_workers(N) ->
    create_workers(N, _Pids=[]).

create_workers(0, Pids) -> Pids;
create_workers(N, Pids) ->
    Pid = spawn(a, worker, []),
    create_workers(N-1, [Pid|Pids]).

test()->
    N = 4,
    Workers = create_workers(N),
    RandNum1 = rand:uniform(N),
    RandNum2 = rand:uniform(N),
    Worker1 = lists:nth(RandNum1, Workers),
    Worker2 = lists:nth(RandNum2, Workers),

    Worker1 ! hello,
    Worker1 ! {hi, self()},

    Worker2 ! {xxxx, self()},
    Worker2 ! {hi, self()},

    Results = get_results(2, _Acc=[]),
    io:format("Worker results: ~w~n", [Results]),
    terminate(Workers).


get_results(0, Acc) -> Acc;
get_results(N, Acc) ->
    Result = receive
                 {Msg, _From} -> Msg
             end,
    get_results(N-1, [Result|Acc]).

terminate(Workers) ->
    lists:foreach(fun(Worker) -> Worker ! stop end,
            Workers).
```

In the shell:

```
6> c(a).    
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

7> a:test().
Worker results: [bye,bye]
Bad message received by worker: <0.96.0>
Bad message received by worker: <0.99.0>
Worker <0.96.0> terminated.
Worker <0.99.0> terminated.
Worker <0.98.0> terminated.
Worker <0.97.0> terminated.
ok
```